# External Data Input PSCS6 with text changes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

Basically Im a small time graphic designer trying to simplify some small tasks that will be constantly pop up. My objective is to automate Twitter banners where the user can input their Name 'Alias' LastName and it will print out the banner in a jpg/png file ready to be uploaded to twitter.

I have made a C++ program that basically asks the user for their name and what division they are in. The program then saves the name to a text file and depending what division of selected opens a PSD batch file and runs it. Photoshop then takes the txt file the Program created and uses that to input the new text line.

My problem is that mid text I need to change the colour and size of the text. Example 20size, normal "Name" 30Size, Bold "Alias" 20size, Normal "Lastname". Anyone know how I could do this? It all has to be in one text line.

At the current stage of I have it working however it out puts the text in all the same size font and colour.

EDIT: And a side note is that I cant make them all separate fields as it needs to be spaced evenly. Eg longer firstnames would overlap the alias.

Comment: Hey, Sounds like you made a pretty cool thing with C++, however, photoshop cannot target a specific area on a single line as the name, alias etc will always be a different length. You could however, try making 4 different text areas if possible and position them on the same line? and then apply an action specific to each one and then you would need to write a photoshop script to call each one. (this is only a guestimate!)